# ADO wiki stats generator charting

Tags: statistics, powershell, git

I'm planning on adding an automated process to generate some stats once a week from a git repository, generates a markdown file with some stats, but looking for some suggestions for generating some graphs or formatting.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates some stats based on the git repository url
#>
param(
    #URI of the git location for the repo
    [string] $gitURI = "https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc.git"
)
$Currentlocation = "C:\_Builds"
$Project = $($gitURI.Split('/')[-1]).replace('.git', '')
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Generating stats for $Project"

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Currentlocation
Set-Location $Currentlocation

If (Test-path $Currentlocation\$Project) { Remove-item $Currentlocation\$Project -Force -Recurse }

git -c http.sslVerify=false -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false clone --no-checkout $gitURI
git config http.sslVerify false

Set-Location $Currentlocation\$Project
If (Test-path .\stats.md) { Remove-item .\stats.md }

$DefaultBranch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
git checkout $DefaultBranch .mailmap
add-Content .\stats.md "# Statistics`n"

[int]$commit_count = git rev-list HEAD --count
[string]$commit_first = git log --reverse --format="format:%as" --all | select-object -first 1
[string]$commit_last = git log --reverse --format="format:%as" --all | select-object -last 1
add-Content .\stats.md "Commits: $commit_count"
add-Content .\stats.md "Initial Commit: $commit_first"
add-Content .\stats.md "Last Commit: $commit_last"

$contributors = git shortlog HEAD --summary --numbered --no-merges
$authors_and_counts = $contributors.split("\n")
add-Content .\stats.md "`n"
add-Content .\stats.md "## All Contributors`n"
Add-Content .\stats.md "|**Author**|**Commit Count**|"
Add-Content .\stats.md "|--|--|"

foreach ($author_count in $authors_and_counts) {
    Add-Content .\stats.md "|$($author_count.split("`t")[1])|$($author_count.split("`t")[0])|"
}
add-Content .\stats.md "`n"
add-Content .\stats.md "## Top Contributors`n"
add-Content .\stats.md "::: mermaid"
add-Content .\stats.md "pie showData"
foreach ($author_count in $authors_and_counts) {
    if ($([math]::round(($author_count.split("`t")[0] / $commit_count) * 100, 2)) -gt 0) {
        Add-Content .\stats.md "  `"$($author_count.split("`t")[1])`" : $([math]::round(($author_count.split("`t")[0] / $commit_count) * 100,2))"
    }
}
add-Content .\stats.md ":::`n"

$gitHist = (git log --format="%aI`t") | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header ("Date")
foreach ($row in $gitHist) {
    $row.Date = $row.Date -as [datetime]
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DayOfWeek -Value $row.Date.DayOfWeek
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hour -Value $row.Date.Hour
}

add-Content .\stats.md "## Commits per weekday`n"
add-Content .\stats.md "::: mermaid"
add-Content .\stats.md "pie showData"
$DayofWeekStats = ($gitHist | Group-object { $_.DayOfWeek })
foreach ($DayCount in $DayofWeekStats) {
    Add-Content .\stats.md "  `"$($DayCount.Name)`" : $([math]::round(($DayCount.count / $commit_count) * 100,2))"
}
add-Content .\stats.md ":::`n"

add-Content .\stats.md "## Commits per day hour`n"
add-Content .\stats.md "::: mermaid"
add-Content .\stats.md "pie showData"
$perHourStats = ($gitHist | Group-object { $_.Hour })
foreach ($hourCount in $perHourStats) {
    Add-Content .\stats.md "  `"$($hourCount.Name)`" : $([math]::round(($hourCount.count / $commit_count) * 100,2))"
}
add-Content .\stats.md ":::`n"
```